# Looking for a reliable consistent site testing tool

Tags: performance, testing

I've been using GTMetrix for a while now but have noticed that the results are very inconsistent - and sometimes just wrong. Gidnetwork will show compression working perfectly and GTM continues to state it's not enabled. GTM is showing "avoid bad requests" with the links it lists as being from a 3 week old version of the site.

It's like chasing smoke trying to determine which "tests" are showing accurate information when all testing sites give different results.

Does everyone out there just use all the well known tools and continue to work the site until ALL the tests show clean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few to try:

Google's page-speed insights

webpagetest.org

pingdom.com

try.powermapper.com

Also, you want to make sure your server is in good working order and not hacked. Hacked servers can cause unpredictable results regardless of the testing website you use.

Comment: Googles times are bit slow- not sure why- but generally very reliable. Pingdom is pretty dang good- reliable and accurate- but I have noticed that network lag times (for any of them) can effect results so a couple of tests at different times should be fine enough to give accurate results. There was one other I like, but I cannot remember what that is right now.

Comment: Probably because Google is near los angeles and their connection timings are similar to a los angeles computer when one is used through webpagetest.org.

Comment: Good point! But sometimes I find their times are unbelievable. Especially when compared to any external testing that is done. I just take Google with a grain of salt. Of course my blood pressure is getting rather high...

Comment: LA just seems to have traffic problems all around ;) Thanks for the replies…I tried the ones you listed Mike - pretty good results. Still not sure why some - Google's insights for one - are still showing gzip as not enabled when the others show it working fine. But I agree - pingdom is pretty good!

Comment: google can make anyones blood pressure go high which means its time for me to post my next question regarding google.  As for gzip, make sure you use "vary: accept-encoding" in the outputted HTTP headers and if gzip is in the accept-encoding list for the input header, then the output data needs to be gzipped, otherwise it should be normal and uncompressed.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes - it's definitely a blood-pressure thing ;) So, I use mod_deflate and looking the "vary" function I read an article that said if you use deflate it serves up the correct "vary header" automatically. Is that correct? I do have deflate enabled but still get recommendations from testiing sites that my gzip isn't functioning "well" - it's not a 100%.

Comment: I limit my use of apache modules because they use memory. I do my gzipping in PHP and then send the appropriate headers on every request. the "vary" header tells browsers that the content served is dependant on the headers listed. For example, accept-encoding.